# Conditional probability of child's height

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that the number of births in a year follow Poisson distribution with intensity $\lambda>0$. If child height is distributed lognormally with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ what is the expected height of a first child that is taller than average?

Is there any smart way to calculate this?

Comment: The Poisson distribution doesn't enter into it, since it doesn't matter when the child is born; you're just asking for the conditional expectation of the height given that it's above average. This is given in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Conditional_expectation) of the Wikipedia article on the log-normal distribution.